# Sharepoint Group Permission Level

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to change a group permission level independent of a list or list item using JS REST API and if so how. I've seen a lot of ways to change permission levels of a group in relation to a list for example see the following link:

*https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Add-contribute-permissions-to-SharePoint-Group-on-List-Item-via/td-p/124506*

However, I only want to change the permission level of a sitegroup.

Here is what I have thus far,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
  <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15SP.Ribbon.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button type="text/javascript" onclick='changePermissionLevel();'>test</button>
 <div id='dev'></div>
 <form runat="server">
 <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest></form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changePermissionLevel(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/RoleDefinitions(1073741948)/addroleassignment(principalId=9076, roledefId=1073741948)"
        type: "POST",
        headers:{
          "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-length": 32,
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: function(success){
          alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
        },
        error: function(error){
          alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        },
      });
    });
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```